# is there any solution Error while connecting to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, cdc

I Get this error while executing curl -i -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @G:/kafka/kafka/config/db-Connector.json this

{"error_code":500,"message":"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='3.7.0', encodedVersion=3.7.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector', version='3.7.0', encodedVersion=3.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='3.7.0', encodedVersion=3.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='3.7.0', encodedVersion=3.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='3.7.0', encodedVersion=3.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}"}

i have tried running curl -i -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @G:/kafka/kafka/config/db-Connector.json  this command